# I want to draw a digaraph with 4 vertices in overleaf

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can anybody help me in drawing following diagram (a graph connecting to all vertices, where each vertex have selfloops among themselves with arrows) ? 
[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{main node/.style={circle,fill=black!20,draw,minimum size=1cm,inner sep=0pt}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   %%node
    \begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
    \node[main node] (1) {$1$};
    \node[main node] (2) [right = 2cm  of 1]  {$2$};
    \node[main node] (3) [below = 2cm  of 1] {$3$};
    \node[main node] (4) [right = 2cm  of 3] {$4$};
    \path[draw,thick]
    (1) edge node {} (2)
    (1) edge node {} (4)
    (3) edge node {} (2)
    (3) edge node {} (4)
    (2) edge node {} (2)
    ;
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. How can we help you? Draw it instead of you? Please, show what you try so far. At least provide a sketch of your digraph.

Comment: I'm in need of selfloop for every vertex 1,2,3,4.I tried using tikzpicture positioning library which is not coming on overleaf page

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). By the way, please make your [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)compilable with `\documentclass{...}` and the required `\usepackage`'s, . That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand... So help them help you `(-;`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `(1) edge [in=150,out=90,looseness=5,->] (1)` to create self loop for `(1)` node, where `looseness`  define how "loose" the curve will be.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{main node/.style={circle,fill=black!20,draw,minimum size=1cm,inner sep=0pt}}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
   %%node
    \begin{scope}[xshift=4cm,>=stealth]
    \node[main node] (1) {$1$};
    \node[main node] (2) [right = 2cm  of 1]  {$2$};
    \node[main node] (3) [below = 2cm  of 1] {$3$};
    \node[main node] (4) [right = 2cm  of 3] {$4$};
    \path[draw,thick]
    (1) edge  (2)
    (1) edge  (4)
    (3) edge  (2)
    (3) edge  (4)
    (2) edge  (2)
    (1) edge [in=150,out=90,looseness=5,->] (1)
    (2) edge [in=30, out=90,looseness=5,->] (2)
    (3) edge [in=150,out=90,looseness=5,->] (3)
    (4) edge [in=30, out=90,looseness=5,->] (4)
    ;
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]